# LockWindowsUpdate Works in Office 2010 but not Office 2016

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have, for some time, been using the LockWindowUpdate API to prevent screen flicker and speed up code execution in MS Word.  It works in Office 2010 (64 Bit).

It does not work as expected in Office 2016 (neither 32 nor 64 Bit) and I'm at a loss as to how to resolve - any tips, tricks, or explanations welcome.

```
#If Win64 And VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function LockWindowUpdate Lib "user32" (ByVal hWndLock As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassname As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function LockWindowUpdate Lib "user32" (ByVal hWndLock As Long) As Long
#End If
```

The following works in MS Word 2010, but not in Word 2016 both PCs are running Win 10. AFAICT the call to FindWindow is NOT the problem, I've confirmed that `docHandle` gets a non-zero value.

```
Public Sub FreezeWord()
    #If VBA7 Then
        Dim docHandle As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim docHandle As Long
    #End If

    ' OpusApp = code name for MS Word
    docHandle = FindWindow("OpusApp", Application.ActiveDocument.Name & " - " & Application.Caption)

    If CBool(docHandle) Then
        LockWindowUpdate docHandle  ' Does not work: 32 bit, Word 2016
    End If
End Sub
```

Ref for more info: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx (scroll down to: Eliminating Screen Flicker During VBProject Code)

Comment: Can you not use the Application.screenupdsting property instead..

Comment: @StevenLaycock thanks for the suggestion, I use that as well, but it tends to reset itself during code execution (for want of a better way of explaining),  LockWindowUpdate has been much more robust. Actually the full code FreezeWord also contains `.ScreenUpdating = False` , but I took it out because  it was a potential distraction and I didn't feel like defending the apparent redundancy ;-)

Comment: Sounds like you need to audit the use of Application.screenupdating in your code. The only other simple solution I could suggest is to minimise the affected windows (with a suitable progress bar for the user so they don't panic when their document disappears.).

Comment: IIRCC `.ScreenUpdating` turns itself back on after things like: updating fields, showing hidden bookmarks, adding things to documents... I can't say for sure that it's these specific things, but these _kind_ of things... 

It was using `Application.Visible = False` ... that freaked people out :-/

It would be a chore to identify all the possible ways that `.ScreenUpdating` resets itself... I'm more interested in understanding why LockWindowUpdate is not working and if there is something similar that I could use :-)

Comment: You could define an event that runs every X seconds which checks a flag to see if screen updating should be turned off and if so turn it off.

Comment: Hmmm that's an interesting thought... I imagine I'd need to have a few DoEvents to allow it to do its thing... Wonder what performance would be like...

Comment: Less than 10 seconds of googling got me to this.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-lockwindowupdate  The pertinent part of which is  "The purpose of the LockWindowUpdate function is to permit drag/drop feedback to be drawn over a window without interference from the window itself. ... Use the WM_SETREDRAW message to disable redrawing of a particular window." where WM_SETREDRAW is a link to   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/gdi/wm-setredraw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181611/discussion-between-slowlearner-and-steven-laycock).

Comment: If you're getting screen flicker then you probably should review your code. Does it contain a lot of "Selection" and "Activate"? If yes, work directly with Word's objects, instead. That will greatly reduce screen flicker *and* speed things up considerably...

Comment: Hi @CindyMeister thanks for the tip - I've already stripped out all possible use of `Selection` - first step of every new interaction is to, e.g. `Set tmpRng = Selection.Range`, Selection is only used for those awkward times when manipulation is not possible with a range and `.Activate` is barely used, if at all.

Comment: Anyway, it's NOT so much flicker that I'm trying to avoid... I just don't want my users to see all the changes as they occur on the document as they happen :-/   As a welcome side effect, I found that locking the screen significantly sped up code execution... and I want that performance gain back!